# How to properly set GEOIP_PATH for Django in OS X?

Tags: python, django, macos, python-2.7

I'm just doing my first steps with Python a Django and I'd like to use it with GeoIP on my Mac. I've used Homebrew and pip for installing everything I need, but I haven't figured out how to set path for GeoIP. So I always get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geoip/base.py", line 91, in __init__
    if not path: raise GeoIPException('GeoIP path must be provided via parameter or the GEOIP_PATH setting.')
django.contrib.gis.geoip.base.GeoIPException: GeoIP path must be provided via parameter or the GEOIP_PATH setting.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the GeoIP data which you can [download from MaxMind](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/), and you need to set up GEOIP_PATH in your settings.py module to point to wherever you download that GeoIP data.

Your directory structure might not be exactly the same as this, but for me I have

```
<project directory>
    ...
    geoip
    ...
    <app_directory>
        settings.py
    ...
```

In my settings.py I have a ROOT_PATH set up to refer to the project directory, so

```
GEOIP_PATH = ROOT_PATH + '/geoip'
```

Download the binary / gzip version of the GeoIP data you need, unzip it and put it in that geoip directory.

Answer (score 0):

Same way as every other Django setting: via the `settings` module for the project.

Comment: And where can I find the path if I've installed GeoIP via pip. There is no /usr/local/share/GeoIP/ folder.

Comment: Wherever you installed the GeoIP data.